# Haskell Servant empty route combinator

Tags: haskell, servant

I'm writing up some CRUD helpers for fun and profit, and I'm finding myself needing an empty or noop route. The `mempty` to `:>`, if you will.

This is what I'd like to write:

```
type Index model =
  Reassoc (QueryParams model :> Get '[JSON] (Collection model))

type family Reassoc xs where
  Reassoc ((x :> y) :> z) = Reassoc (x :> Reassoc (y :> z))
  Reassoc (x :> y) = x :> y

type family QueryParams model

type instance QueryParams User =
  MakeQueryParams '[ '("organizationId", Int) ]
```

That all of course builds up to this guy:

```
type family MakeQueryParams xs where
  MakeQueryParams ( '(sym, ty) ': xs ) 
    = QueryParam sym ty :> MakeQueryParams xs
  MakeQueryParams '[] 
    = ... :(
```

## Is there an empty route combinator?

I've worked around this thus far by using a `next` parameter in those families, but it's a lot less idiomatic for Servant.

```
type family MakeQueryParams xs next where
    MakeQueryParams '[] next =
        next
    MakeQueryParams ('(sym, ty) ': xs) next =
        QueryParam sym ty :> MakeQueryParams xs next

type Index model = QueryParams model (Get '[JSON] (Collection model))

type family QueryParams model next

type instance QueryParams User next =
    MakeQueryParams '[ '("organizationId", Int) ] next
```

Comment: I'd say the version with `next` is great and perfectly idiomatic (or at least much more than your other attempt). You don't need `Reassoc`. I'd also argue that something like `(QueryParam ... :> QueryParam ...) :> Get ...` shouldn't even be kind-correct. The fact that it currently is is an accident / compromise.

Answer (score 0):

if you really insist on writing

```hs
type API = QueryParams '[ '("id", Int) ] :> Get '[JSON] Bool
```

you combining your `foldr` like idea/solution (which is completely fine) with a new combinator:

```hs
data QueryParams (ps :: [(Symbol, *)])

instance HasServer api ctx
  => HasServer (QueryParams '[] :> api) ctx where
    type ServerT (QueryParams '[] api) m = ServerT api m

    route = ...

instance HasServer (QueryParam sym ty :> MakeQueryParams ('(sym, ty) ': ps) api) ctx
  => HasServer (QueryParams ('(sym, ty) ': ps) api) ctx where
    type ServerT (QueryParams ('(sym, ty) ': ps) api) m = ...

    route = ...
```

Writing separate instance for nil and cons cases will make implementation of instances more direct.

One can think that we *have to* introduce new combinator, as otherwise we cannot plug type family in the right place. A bit like we sometimes need to write `newtype`s to write different instances.